# Unable to connect to the remote server asp.net IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I have this REST Api request

```
public bool GetResponse(object bodyRequest)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            
            var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyRequest);
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedObject);

            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }

            bool resp = false;
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                var streamData = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamData);
                object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(objResponse.ToString());
                streamData.Close();
                response.Close();
            }

            return resp;
        }
```

When i try to call this request inside an asp.net application (.NET 4.7) hosted in IIS Server, i have this error:
[image]

But when i call this request inside a console application outside IIS, it works perfectly.

I tried configure proxy settings in my web.config:

```
<system.net>
     <defaultProxy> 
          <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="http://xxxxxxxxx:8080" bypassonlocal="false"/> 
    </defaultProxy> 
  </system.net>
```

... i tried to put this before the requisition

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Seems to be an IIS problem, since the console application connects normally, anybody help me?

Comment: Any inner exceptions?

Comment: Can you get to that URL with a browser from the computer that's running IIS?